# Chrome redirecting to favicon.ico with Redirect::intended()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I just noticed that on Google Chrome its redirecting to http://example.com/favicon.ico when you use Redirect::intended(). I thought maybe it was because I don't have a favicon so I added one but still no luck. It shows the correct url before logging in but when you login it just Redirects back to favicon.ico. It only happens on Google Chrome. Is anyone else having this problem I've googled it & only found this one by Jason Lewis http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=305

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a `favicon.ico` file in your document root, and it's still redirecting you? Make sure that your `.htaccess` is letting files slip through, and clear the Laravel session cache, by deleting the files in `storage/session`. Then it should work as Laravel will only handle redirects to routes it actually handles, that is, those that slip through the `.htaccess` rules.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I tried to clear the session and it still redirects to favicon.ico. I noticed when you run the php Internal server Google Chrome tries to get the favicon.ico over and over. One other thing the redirect to favicon.ico only happens on post of a form on Chrome. Oh and I started fresh with a new install of Laravel to though I thought maybe I could have got a buggy install.